# error occurs when vb.net application is published

Tags: vb.net

How can I solve this error when the application is published:

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

You probably have just installed it, but you've done it running the setup from a different location.
Uninstall the application and run again the setup. Remember to run the setup from the same location when you update it.
I'm not 100% sure about it, but form my experience it's correct.